# Command Parameter TextBox: The name "X" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, textbox, parameter-passing

I get this message: The name "PINTextBox" does not exist in the current context.

..when I use this code

```
      protected void SqlDataSource9_Selecting(object sender,
SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
e.Command.Parameters["@PIN"].Value = PINTextBox;
}
```

The code works when I use a value of 3, but I want textbox values to be passed into the @PIN parameter and not just 3

```
      protected void SqlDataSource9_Selecting(object sender,
SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
e.Command.Parameters["@PIN"].Value = 3;
}
```

PINTextbox code is

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
DataKeyNames="ID" GroupItemCount="2">
...
<EditItemTemplate>
...
<asp:TextBox ID="PINTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PIN") %>'/>
...
</EditItemTemplate>
...
</asp:ListView>
```

Is it giving me this message because the textbox is listed in SqlDataSource1 and not SqlDataSource9?

If so, is there any way for me to get around this still using two different data sources? Or how can I pass the data in PINTextBox to my command and into my select statement (not listed because it appears to work when I have the value 3 in the command)?

Thanks and let me know if you need more code.

Comment: You would need to use TextBox.Text to get a string value from the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the label/textbox using the listview's selectedindex and then extract the text as shown below.
(Not sure why you would like to use the textbox but you can use the label; the textbox code is commented).
You can replace "PINLabel" below with the actual ID for your label in ItemTemplate. 
This code will be invoked the first time you load the page, hence you may need to take care of putting a condition for postback.

```
    protected void SqlDataSource9_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        //TextBox txtPIN = ListView1.Items[ListView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("PINTextBox") as TextBox;
        //e.Command.Parameters["@PIN"].Value = txtPIN.Text;
        Label lblPIN = ListView1.Items[ListView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("PINLabel") as Label;
        e.Command.Parameters["@PIN"].Value = lblPIN.Text;
    }
```

You need to ensure that this control is present in the SelectedItemTemplate as well like this:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            DataKeyNames="ID">
            ......
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                 ......
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="PINTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PIN") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            ......
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                ......
                    <td><asp:Label ID="PINLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PIN") %>' /></td>
                ......
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            ......
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                ......
                    <td><asp:Label ID="PINLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PIN") %>' /></td>
                ......
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

**Old Answer (IGNORE):**

> Use ".Text" for PINTextBox!
>       protected void SqlDataSource9_Selecting(object sender,
>       SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
>       {
>       e.Command.Parameters["@PIN"].Value = PINTextBox.Text;
>       }

Comment: Tried it and I received the same error: Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'PINTextBox' does not exist in the current context....Line 68:     e.Command.Parameters["@PIN"].Value = PINTextBox.Text;..... Will try myrow mentioned above...

Answer (score 0):

You need to know which row's TextBox we're talking about.

```
//myRow contains the row that was just selected
TextBox txtPin = (TextBox)myRow.FindControl ("PINTextBox");
e.Command.Parameters["@PIN"].Value = txtPin.Text;
```

Comment: I just tried your code and received the following: Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'myrow' does not exist in the current context....Line 69:     TextBox txtPin = (TextBox)myrow.FindControl("PINTextBox");...I'm still looking into this method but so far no luck.

Comment: um, I didn't wave a magic wand. You'll need to make a field called myRow or something like it to hold the selected ListView row, and populate it on some event.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info (minus sarcasm), I'm new at this :)